# primeNG ConfirmationService and MessageService error

Tags: primeng, angular11

Error: node_modules/primeng/api/messageservice.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved
to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (primeng/api) which declares MessageService has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

3 export declare class MessageService {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/primeng/api/confirmationservice.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (primeng/api) which declares ConfirmationService has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see
```

if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

```
3 export declare class ConfirmationService {
```

can you please help me and thanks
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: What version of PrimeNG are you using? Have you imported in providers ConfirmationService and MessageService?

Comment: providers: [UserService, MessageService, ConfirmationService] and im using     "primeng": "^11.2.3", and angular 11

Comment: It's weird. Try delete node_modules and install again.